# Serialize/deserialize int array to char array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a int array to char array and write it to a stream like this:

```
size_t arraySize = 10;
int* intArray = new int[arraySize];

std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << "foo1=test,arraySize=10,array=";

char* charArrayPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intArray);
buffer.write(charArrayPtr,arraySize*sizeof(int));

auto str = buffer.str();
```

Everything works as expected but there is one problem I really can't wrap my head around. Let's say I want to deserialize the string and for the sake of doing it easier, I would like to split the string and use a delimiter "," (for example).

That will only work until the int array which is converted to char* will eventually match the delimiter as well since the size of the array can differ (10-10000000)

One other way is to split the string all the way until I get to `array=` but then again, the code gets ugly and even more messy if I want to add even more stuff later.

Do you guys happen to have any suggestions which doesn't include other libs?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't understand why you want to add a delimiter since you can't trust them anyway. There are numbers like 44 which will also creates a `,`.in your stream.

Comment: Another think that could interest you. There is something called *byte order*. A CPU with x86 architecture uses *little endian*, other architectures may use another one. If you want to communicate with other systems, It may be good practice to convert the integers to *big endian* (In many protocols also called *network byte order*).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simpler than you think. You could simply use a for loop:

```
size_t arraySize = 10;
int* intArray = new int[arraySize];

std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << "foo1=test,arraySize=10,array=";

char* charArrayPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intArray);
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ ){
    buffer.write(&charArrayPtr[i*sizeof(int)], sizeof(int));

    // Write separator here
    if( i != arraySize - 1 )  // Don't separate after the last one
        buffer.write(", ", 2);
}

auto str = buffer.str();
```